# How to iterate over files with quotes in filename?

Tags: linux, bash

I have set of files in /home/user/source. One file in this set has name **'e e'** (with single quotes). When I tried to loop over this set of files and print all filenames I got this file with name **e e** (quotes disappered). How write this loop to save this quotes in output? Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for existedFile in "$(ls /home/user/source)"
do
    echo $existedFile
done
```

Confused moment here is when I just use `ls /home/user/source` output is correct.

Comment: use a glob: `for existedFile in /home/user/source/*; do printf '%s\n' "$existedFile"; done`

Comment: doesn't work in my case

Comment: "One file in this set has name 'e e' (with single quotes)." It doesn't. It is `ls` quoting the name with a space in it.

Comment: I heard about it, but I set this 'e e' filename manually to check how it would be working

Comment: @Alkaf: What command did you use to set it?

Comment: @choroba touch 'e e'

Comment: Do what the `bash`  tag you used says and copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net to fix most if not all of your problems.

Comment: @Alkaf: That creates a file named `e e`, quotes are removed from the command line during quote removal (see `man bash`). Use `touch "'e e'"` or `touch \'e\ e\'` to create a file named `'e e'`.

Comment: @Alkaf _"doesn't work in my case"_ : how so?

Comment: Try `touch e\ e` (that's e, a backslash, a space, and another e) instead and see what kind of file you've got. Then maybe read some `bash` documentation.

Answer (score -1):

[Don't Parse the Output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

The output of `ls` can contain anything. It can contain whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols, etc. This can be extremely harmful in a script.

Instead, iterate over a glob: `*`. An asterisk is shorthand for "everything in this directory". Bash will take care of the iteration over files. If you need to match a particular file type/pattern, you can use `*.java`, `file*.f90`, etc.